# Google Apps Script Gmail Star Search Result

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the beginning of a script (below) to search and star a specific message, but the problem is the GmailApp.search() method returns a string which GmailApp.starMessage() cannot process (error is "Cannot convert Array to GmailMessage").  How can I convert the search from a string or correlate it somehow to a usable object?

```
function starEmail() {
  var email = GmailApp.search('from:address@email.com is:unread')
  GmailApp.starMessage(email);
}
```

Comment: I realize that... that's why I'm asking for help.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Comment: search does not return a string as you say. the documentation will show you what it returns.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the GmailApp documentation, it looks like you're going to have to add an extra step between your `.search()` and your `.starMessage()` methods.

`.search()` returns type `GmailThread[]`, while `.starMessage()` requires type `GmailMessage`. You will need to use the `.getMessages()` method in the `GmailThread` class to convert your search result array into an array of messages, which you can then star:

```
function starEmail(){
    var threads = GmailApp.search('search:parameters'); //returns array

    //assuming search returns one thread as question suggests
    //otherwise, a for-in loop would probably be appropriate here.
    var message = threads[0].getMessages(); //returns array

    GmailApp.starMessage(message[0]) 
}
```

[search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String))

[getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages())

[starMessage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#starMessage(GmailMessage))